# C# convert bit to boolean

Tags: c#, ado.net

I have a Microsoft SQL Server database that contains a data field of `BIT` type.

This field will have either `0` or `1` values to represent false and true.

I want when I retrieve the data to convert the value I got to `false` or `true` without using if-condition to convert the data to `false` if it is `0` or `true` if it is `1`.

I'm wondering if there is a function in C# would do this direct by passing bit values to it?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Depending on how are you performing the SQL queries it may depend. For example if you have a [data reader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.aspx) you could directly [read a boolean value](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getboolean(VS.80).aspx):

```
using (var conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
{
    conn.Open();
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT isset_field FROM sometable";
    using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            bool isSet = reader.GetBoolean(0);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When executing a stored procedure or UDF that only returns a BIT, does it work without the need to `Read()`, i.e. like this: `bool isSet = cmd.ExecuteReader().GetBoolean(0);`?

Answer (score 40):

```
DataReader.GetBoolean(x)
```

or

```
Convert.ToBoolean(DataRow[x])
```

Comment: `Convert.ToBoolean((byte)1);` returns `true`

Answer (score 14):

How are you extracting the fields from the database?

The [`SqlDataReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w9y9ttex.aspx) class has a [`GetBoolean`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getboolean.aspx) method which does the translation for you:

```
bool yourBoolean = reader.GetBoolean(reader.GetOrdinal("Your_Bit_Column"));
```

Answer (score 5):

[GetBoolean](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbdatareader.getboolean%28v=VS.71%29.aspx) will do this automatically.

Answer (score 3):

`SqlDataSource` from ASP.NET 2.0 returns `0` and `1` for `BIT` fields.

`SqlDataSource` from ASP.NET 4.0 returns appropriate string - `Boolean.TrueString` (`"True"`) or  `Boolean.FalseString` (`"False"`).

Comment: @Guillaume: SQL type BIT or .NET type byte?