# Bit to Boolean Conversions happenig

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, datatable, ado.net

When I execute a query(c#) the bit(0 or 1) fields in DB become boolean(true or false) in datatable. How we can achieve the same value as in Database in result set. Please help.

Comment: Did you see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2767352/c-sharp-convert-bit-to-boolean

Comment: That already happens. A `bit` result is boolean. You must read the result incorrectly (eg. force cast it to something else).

Comment: Can you share your code?

Answer (score 2):

If you `select` it as an integer, it will not be converted to a `boolean` by ADO.NET:

```
select  cast(BitField as int) as BitFieldAlias
```

Answer (score 1):

In your ADO.NET query, you could convert the BIT field into an INT datatype.

```
DECLARE @bit BIT
SET @bit = 1

SELECT CONVERT(INT, @bit)
```