# Display bit values from database in a combobox

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I've different columns, named bit_SocietyTypeBunglow, bit_SocietyTypeFlat and so on used as flags. Now I would like to retrieve appropriate names ('Bungalow', 'Flat' and so on) for all flags that are set to true (i.e. equal 1) as a list I can use in a combobox in my program.

This is what I tried, but it gives me the names as colums, not as rows.

```
  BEGIN
    SELECT 
      CASE WHEN bit_SocietyTypeBunglow = 1 THEN 'Bunglows' ELSE NULL END AS Bunglow, 
      CASE WHEN bit_SocietyTypeFlat = 1 THEN 'Flats' ELSE NULL END AS Flat, 
      CASE WHEN bit_SocietyTypePent = 1 THEN 'Pent Houses' ELSE NULL END AS Pent_House, 
      CASE WHEN bit_SocietyTypeRow = 1 THEN 'Row Houses' ELSE NULL END AS Row_House
    FROM tblSocietyDetail WHERE str_SocietyName = @strSocietyName
```

Actually My table and its columns are like this:
[table data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wTFVt.png)

And i want my combo to be filled like this:
[combobox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eYKB1.jpg)

I'm using stored procedures to write this query

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2767352/c-sharp-convert-bit-to-boolean

Comment: Did you try _anything_ so far?

Comment: BEGIN
  SELECT  CASE WHEN bit_SocietyTypeBunglow = 1 THEN 'Bunglows' ELSE NULL END AS Bunglow, 
  CASE WHEN bit_SocietyTypeFlat = 1 THEN 'Flats' ELSE NULL END AS Flat,
  CASE WHEN bit_SocietyTypePent = 1 THEN 'Pent Houses' ELSE NULL END AS Pent_House,
  CASE WHEN bit_SocietyTypeRow = 1 THEN 'Row Houses' ELSE NULL END AS Row_House 
  FROM tblSocietyDetail
  WHERE str_SocietyName = @strSocietyName END                                                                            I've tried this but it retrives only the first row i.e 'bunglows' in combobox

Comment: please update your comment in the question..

Comment: Can u provide sample table values & Expected result in combo box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's see if I understand you correctly. You want to have the entries "Flats" and "Pent Houses" in your combobox, if the society only has these two. To get a record per entry you would have to select the table multiple times:

```
SELECT 'Bunglows' 
FROM   tblsocietydetail 
WHERE  str_societyname = @strSocietyName 
       AND bit_societytypebunglow = 1 
UNION 
SELECT 'Flats' 
FROM   tblsocietydetail 
WHERE  str_societyname = @strSocietyName 
       AND bit_societytypeflat = 1 
UNION 
SELECT 'Pent Houses' 
FROM   tblsocietydetail 
WHERE  str_societyname = @strSocietyName 
       AND bit_societytypepent = 1 
UNION 
SELECT 'Row Houses' 
FROM   tblsocietydetail 
WHERE  str_societyname = @strSocietyName 
       AND bit_societytyperow = 1;
```

Comment: Exactly this was what i wanted, Thanks a lot. It really heelped me a lot. :-) Thanks again